# Displaying a tooltip for QTreeWidgetItem when it's hovered without calling setTooltip() for every item

Tags: qt, tooltip, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I want to display a tooltip for `QTreeWidgetItem` that's hovered. However, getting a tooltip is not a very fast process in my case, so I don't want to call `setTooltip()` for every single item. I want to do it on demand, on some event or signal. What's the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution I've found is to subclass `QTreeWidgetItem`, override `virtual QVariant data(int column, int role) const;` and return a tooltip for this item when `data` is called for `Qt::ToolTipRole`.

Comment: lol, so, basically, what i said, but without changing to model/view. Sorry, dunno how didnt realized it had to be a data method in the widget items :S

Comment: @Trompa: Yeah, and without model at all :)

Comment: Anyways, you should try it ;). With QStandardItemModel you would be using QStandardItems pretty much like WidgetItems and you get decoupling.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it should be easier to achieve what you want if you migrate to a QTreeView/Model pattern.

QAbstractItemModel has a role for tooltips: Qt::ToolTipRole

You could subclass a Model to reimplement the

```
QVariant QAbstractItemModel::data ( const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole ) const [pure virtual
```

method.

So, when receives a Qt::TooltipRole, it calculates/recovers from an internal cache.

Comment: Note that, as QTreeWidget inherits from QTreeView, you could assign youe custom model. But it would kind of mixing apples and oranges

Comment: I've never used `QTreeView`, it seems overcomplicated for no good reason (provided that I've never had to do something that's not possible with Widget until now). Is there no way to achieve this with `QTreeWidget`?

Comment: Would it be possible to reimplement `QtreeWidget::mouseEvent()` to get `QHoverEvent`, calculate which item the mouse is over and display a tooltip?

Comment: There is a QEvent::ToolTip, so i figure you could filter the events through an eventfilter (not sure if installed in the treeWidget or in every treeWidgetItem).